# Add all form input value to closest div as class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with a bunch of text inputfield. Each of them is embedded in a div. When the user clicks the save button, i need each of the input values to be added to corresponding div that wraps it as a class. Right after that happens, then next function, which initiates the saving process, should start.

At first I used `on("change")` , but that led to the each noew value to be added as a new class on every keystroke. That way I only had once chance: copy and paste the entire text and don't make a mistake.

```
redips.save = function () {
    // scan timetable content
     $(".input").on("change", "input[type='text']", function() {
            var klasse;
            klasse = $(this).val();
            //alert(klasse);
            $(this).closest('div').addClass(klasse);
        });
    let content = REDIPS.drag.saveContent('table2');
    // and save content
    window.location.href = 'redips_db_save.php?' + content;
};
```

This is the HTML:

```
print "<div id=\"$id\" class=\"input btn btn-secondary redips-drag klasse $class\">$name  
           
            <input type=\"text\" class=\"input\" id=\"addinfo\" value=\"$addinfo\" placeholder=\"Add Info\" name=\"$pos\"></input>
           </div> ";
```

in this `table` (`timetable(..)` creates the `divs` with the `inputs`):

```
 <table id="table2" class="table table-responsive">
                    <colgroup>
                        <col max-width="50" />
                        <col max-width="100" />
                        <col max-width="100" />
                        <col max-width="100" />
                        <col max-width="100" />
                        <col max-width="100" />
                        <col max-width="100" />
                        <col max-width="100" />
                    </colgroup>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <!-- if checkbox is checked, clone school subjects to the whole table row  -->
                            <td class="redips-mark blank">
                                <input id="week" type="checkbox" title="Apply school subjects to the week" checked />
                                <input id="report" type="checkbox" title="Show subject report" />
                            </td>
                            <td class="redips-mark dark">Monday</td>
                            <td class="redips-mark dark">Tuesday</td>
                            <td class="redips-mark dark">Wednesday</td>
                            <td class="redips-mark dark">Thursday</td>
                            <td class="redips-mark dark">Friday</td>
                            <td class="redips-mark dark">Saturday</td>
                            <td class="redips-mark dark">Sunday</td>
                        </tr>

                        <?php timetable('Week 1', 1) ?>
                        <?php timetable('Week 2', 2) ?>
                        <?php timetable('Week 3', 3) ?>
                        <?php timetable('Week 4', 4) ?>
                        <?php timetable('Week 5', 5) ?>

                        <?php timetable('Week 6', 6) ?>
                        <?php timetable('Week 7', 7) ?>
                        <?php timetable('Week 8', 8) ?>
                        <?php timetable('Week 9', 9) ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

here is what I have tried then:

```
redips.save = function () {
    // scan timetable content
            var klasse;
        //get input values from inputs
            klasse = $(".input").val();
            //alert(klasse);
            //add each value to the closest div class
            $(this).closest('div').addClass(klasse);
        
    let content = REDIPS.drag.saveContent('table2');
    // and save content
    window.location.href = 'redips_db_save.php?' + content;
};
```

Alert(klasse) alerts without text - so I guess the problem starts with a wrong selection.
Can you help me and point me in the right direction?

thank you!

Comment: Please post the html for the form